# AWS Load balancer force Wordpress URL to specific instance

Tags: linux, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have a 'classic' load balancer configured that has two EC2 instances sitting beneath it. I also have a Wordpress DB hosted on a separate RDS instance.

After some research into maintaining a single Wordpress instance on multiple EC2 servers and keeping sync between the filesystem i.e. installing plugins etc seems to be a nightmare.

Is there a way to force a URL pattern (/wordpress/ --> EC2 server 1) to a specific instance so I don't have to maintain sync between filesystems?

Maybe there is a much simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only run Wordpress on one of the instances? What is the other instance for then? Anyway, you can't do what you are asking with a classic load balancer. It is very easy to do with the newer Application Load Balancers though.

Comment: It hosts a large app, but it's deployed via CodeDeploy

Comment: So you have both servers hosting a large app, which is load balanced. And you also want to run Wordpress on one of those same servers? It seems like a much better solution to move Wordpress to a completely separate sever so that it doesn't use up resources on one of the app servers.

Comment: ok so you are suggesting having 3 x ec2 instances - 2 reserved for existing app, and a new one that just hosts wordpress blog. Then I guess a new 'application based LB' that points anything /blog/* to this new instance? Sorry I don't have heaps of experience with infrastructure

Comment: Yes, 3x ec2 servers. 2 are your app servers. 1 is your blog server. Replace your classic load balancer with an Application load balancer. Then configure the ALB to forwared /blog/* to the wordpress server. If you don't want to touch your current load balancer then you could instead use a subdomain like blog.example.com that would point to your wordpress server, instead of a `/blog` path.

Comment: Legend will give this a try Mark and accept your answer